# Script to iterate through lines of alarm log file and execute some lines of code if alarm is active for more than one day

Tags: shell, loops, date, unix

I would like to create a script to loop through lines of alarm log file, extract specific field and then save the result in another external file. The extracted information will then be used to execute additional commands.

Here is an example of the log file and the desired o/p:

> 2016-09-29 23:40:14 GST;2016-09-29 23:40:14 GST;faultManager:network@ET_AO_L_0165_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ET_AO_L_0165_abcd_44159@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
>
> 2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;faultManager:network@ER_AO_L_4283_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ER_AO_L_4283_abcd_10197@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
>
> 2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;faultManager:network@ER_AO_L_4283_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ER_AO_L_4283_abcd_11339@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
>
> 2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;faultManager:network@ER_AO_L_4283_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ER_AO_L_4283_abcd_14179@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
>
> 2016-11-01 11:26:58 GST;2016-11-01 11:26:58 GST;faultManager:network@ET_AO_L_0166_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ET_AO_L_0166_abcd_14126@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
>
> 2016-11-03 10:00:08 GST;2016-11-03 10:00:08 GST;faultManager:network@ET_AO_L_0193_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ET_AO_L_0193_abcd_16113@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;

For each line, it should check if the alarm is active for more than one day (compare to current date), if condition is true then extract the name (ex. ET_AO_L_0165_abcd) and direct it to external file.

Expected o/p (remove duplicates):

> ET_AO_L_0165_abcd
>
> ER_AO_L_4283_abcd
>
> ET_AO_L_0166_abcd
>
> ET_AO_L_0193_abcd

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could the blank line be used as a record separator?

Comment: pls ignore the blank line, i added it just to make it easier to check the contents, thx

Comment: Is this `bash` script?

Comment: yes bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write a small script to achieve this.

```
declare -a array=( $(sed -E 's/^.*faultManager:network@([^@]*)@.*$/\1/' /path/to/log/file ) )
declare -A temp # declaring an associative array ! important.
for elem in "${array[@]}"
do
 temp[$elem]=1 # Array keys can't be duplicated, this is the catch here
done
for index in "${!temp[@]}" # Taking the indexes which is our required values
do
 echo $index >>/path/to/result/file #appending the values to a file.
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i tried but it is giving an error "sed: illegal option -- E", additionally i would like to know if this code will also address the check related to alarm "date" in each line.

Comment: Some systems might not support -E option, use the -r instead